# Keras sequential needs nearly all gpu memory

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network, gpu

I am new to Keras and CNN and currently i am struggeling with my GPU memory.

In short:
As soon as i call tf.keras.Sequential([...]) my GPU memory is nearly completely depleted. Although my model only has 128,312 parameters and my GPU memory is 32 GiB.

In detail:
I use nvidia-smi and see, that my GPU memory is nearly empty but as soon as i inizialize my autoencoder:

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential(\[
    keras.Input(shape=input_shape),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=3, kernel_size=(1,1), activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=4, kernel_size=(1,1), activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=4, kernel_size=(1,1), activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=4, kernel_size=(1,1), activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=4, kernel_size=(1,1), activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(strides=(2,2),padding="same"),

    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=8, kernel_size=(1,1), activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=8, kernel_size=(1,1), activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(strides=(2,2),padding="same"),
    
    ....

\])
```

with the input_shape=(224, 224, 3) my GPU memory is nearly filled up

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      2027      G   /usr/libexec/Xorg                   8MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
[ul_fzx53@uc2n513 ul_fzx53]$ nvidia-smi
Wed May 17 10:17:37 2023       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 525.85.12    Driver Version: 525.85.12    CUDA Version: 12.0     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Tesla V100-SXM2...  On   | 00000000:3A:00.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   37C    P0    55W / 300W |  31451MiB / 32768MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
```

although my model only has:

```
Total params: 128,312
Trainable params: 128,312
Non-trainable params: 0
```

Later on i use batchwise training and still get GPU out of memory errors.

(To compile my model i use `optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.001)` )

i have no clue what i am doing wrong or what i should do.

Comment: What is your batch size when using batchwise training ?

Comment: The batch size i currently use is 32. But after calling the fit function ~2.500 times i get the OOM error. ...First i pre processe the data. After that, i could store all images in one array, which would have the size (81144, 244, 244, 3). So 81144 is the number of images, 244x244 is the size of my images and 3 are the color channels. The array would be 45 GB large. Thats why i split the array into smaller ones, containing a few thousand pictures each and call the fit function with the batch size of 32.

Comment: I suggest you try with batches of 4 images to start with, just to see if you GPU can handle this. Also, a good way to reduce the amount of memory is to convert all images to grayscale (except if you really need colors). Also, you don't need to split the array manually. I would use ImageDataGenerator() from keras, with the flow_from_directory() method, that allows you to import batches directly from the directory where the images are stored.

Comment: Thanks for your advise. But my primary question is, why the keras.Sequential function eats up nearly all my GPU memory? Even though i inizialize a small model, with only 128.312 parameters. That shouldn't use ~31.000 MiB or?

Comment: There is one more thing i don't get which has to do with the GPU memory. If i call the fit function with already small batches of 32, why does it run OOM, even though my GPU memory is huge with 32 GiB? Isn't that just the point of batchwise training, that I have small batches that don't take up all the memory?

... To escape the OOM problem, my idea was to save my model just before the error, then apply K.clear_session() and load it again afterwards. Unfortunately, K.clear_session() does not clear the GPU memory, so this does not work either.

Comment: Ps. I am not working on my own machine but on a server / cluster, can this be related?

Comment: Some things you can try : build a very simple network to see if it works (for example: Conv2D -> Pooling -> Conv2D) to see how it behaves, or try to run your code on Google Colab to use their GPU and see if the problem comes the cluster you are working on (also, they provide real-time graphs showing memory consumption, which could help you understand what is going on).

Comment: For the OOM error, to my knowledge, 32 is not so small for RGB images of 224*224 pixels. I would try smaller to begin with.